# How do I prevent MS Exchange users from forwarding or copying a message sent via System.Net.Mail?

Tags: c#, .net, email, smtpclient, exchange-server-2010

How do I prevent MS Exchange users from forwarding or copying a message sent via System.Net.Mail?

Comment: Don't send the mail in the first place? Beyond that you're out of options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. If the email message was sent via Exchange rather than SMTP, you might be able to...with a server-side Exchange plugin/extension. But if the mail is sent via SMTP and is outside the Exchange server, you're SOL. The mail message is nothing more than a simple text file. Which see [RFC 5322: Internet Message Format](http://tools.ietf.org/pdf/rfc5322.pdf).

Further [SMTP](http://tools.ietf.org/pdf/rfc5321.pdf) itself is a store-and-forward protocol. Every mail server involved in moving the message from sender to recipients gets a copy of the message and can keep it around.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible unless you write an Outlook plugin and even if you do, a determined user will always be able to do it one way or another.

Comment: Yup.  It's even harder to stop copy-paste or screenshots.